# jquery pass parameters on mutual functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a two functions in Jquery to change a `div` to `textarea` on click and making it a `div` on blur. I need to save the `id` of the `div` and use it in a function nested. How can I pass the `id` between these two functions?
 This is my code, which detects th `id` as an event

```
function divClicked(id) {
  console.log("click");
  var divHtml = $(this).html();
  var editableText = $("<textarea />");
  editableText.val(divHtml);
  $(this).replaceWith(editableText);
  editableText.focus();
  // setup the blur event for this new textarea
  var iden = $(this).attr("id");
  editableText.blur(id, editableTextBlurred);
}

function editableTextBlurred(id) {
  console.log("blur");
  var html = $(this).val();
  var viewableText = $("<div>");
  viewableText.html(html);
  $(this).replaceWith(viewableText);
  var descr = viewableText.html();
  // setup the click event for this new div
  cool_function(id, descr);
  $(viewableText).click(id, divClicked);
}
```

Comment: Why not put the id on the textarea?  Then in both cases the id for the div and textarea replacing each other gets set to what it is/was

Comment: Side note you should consider delegate bindings so you don't have to keep re-creating bindings on the swaps.

Comment: each `div` has a variable id. I can not give an specific id to them because my PHP code creates it.

Comment: There isn't a specific id.  `var iden = $(this).attr("id");` is whatever id your php gave it. `editableText.attr('id', iden);` and you are done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *much* better approach would be to use delegated event handlers to switch the element between the types, something like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'div.switch', function() {
  var $textarea = $('<textarea />', { 
    class: 'switch',
    html: $(this).html(),
    id: this.id
  });
  $(this).replaceWith($textarea);
  $textarea.focus();
}).on('blur', 'textarea.switch', function() {
  var $div = $('<div />', {
    class: 'switch',
    html: this.value,
    id: this.id
  });
  $(this).replaceWith($div);
  cool_function(this.id, this.value);
});

function cool_function(id, html) {
  // your logic here...
  console.log(id, html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switch" id="foo">Foo <strong>bar</strong></div>
<div class="switch" id="foo">Fizz buzz</div>
```

The benefit of this method is that it will work for any instance of the `div.switch` in the HTML with no amendments to the JS, and it's only two event handlers instead of having to add/remove them each time the elements are swapped.

You could go even further and just use a `contenteditable` div, but it depends on how your page is structured, and how the server is setup to receive data.